# emacs 28.1 unable to launch slime (cl is deprecated)

Tags: slime

I installed emacs via brew: `brew install emacs` and got version 28.1 (my OS version is macOS 11.6.1).
I immediately ran `package-install` + `slime`.

When I run `slime` command I get:

`Package cl is deprecated`

When I run the command for 2nd time I get:

`Wrong number of arguments (3 . 4), 2`

I am complete newbie to emacs and lisp, I'm just trying to set up the environment so I can complete tutorial.

When running with `toggle-debug-on-error` option I get the following output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 4) 2)
  #f(compiled-function (obsolete-name current-name when &optional docstring) "Make OBSOLETE-NAME a variable alias f$
  (define-obsolete-variable-alias 'common-lisp-glossary-fun 'common-lisp-hyperspec-glossary-function)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-964107> nil "/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.26.1/li..." nil t)  ; Readin$
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.26.1/li..." "/Users/user/.emacs.d/$
  require(hyperspec "lib/hyperspec")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.26.1/sl..." nil t)  ; Reading at bu$
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.26.1/sl..." "/Users/user/.emacs.d/$
  autoload-do-load((autoload "slime" "Start a Lisp subprocess and connect to its Swank s..." t nil) slime)
  command-execute(slime record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "slime" "slime")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "slime" "slime")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: "Package cl is deprecated" doesn't mean `cl` doesn't work (it is still present, and it works just fine).  It's just a suggestion (to the authors of the code in question) to switch to `cl-lib`.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and paste the backtrace from the error into your question.

Comment: @phils thanks for suggestion, I updated my question with the output

Comment: This is apparently a duplicate of the problem raised in question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71503/105. (Can't close as dup because that one doesn't have an upvoted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `define-obsolete-variable-alias` is defined as an Emacs Lisp macro.

I would like to guess that there might be something in how the *macro expansion* for `define-obsolete-variable-alias` is being compiled, such that may be resulting in the error.

If it may be possible to develop a short sort of workaround for the error, the following should serve to ensure that `hyperspec.el` is newly recompiled by Emacs. This uses a syntax like for keys/commands entered in the Emacs *minibufer*

1. `M-X find-library RET slime RET`
2. `M-X find-file RET lib/hyperspec.el RET`
3. `M-X byte-compile-file RET RET`

Concerning the two 'RET' i.e 'return' keys entered with the third item: When not specifying any file in the interactive call to `byte-compile-file`, or when entering an empty string when it asks for a file in the minibuffer, then it should use the file in the selected buffer - e.g `hyperspec.el` under that source location.

This basically recompiles the `"lib/hyperspec.el"` located under the same `load-path` directory as `"slime.el"`. This recompiled `hyperspec.elc` would then be loaded when the following is evaluated newly, in `slime.el`

> `(require 'hyperspec "lib/hyperspec")`

One of `slime.elc` (byte-compiled file) or `slime.el` (the source file for `slime.elc`) would have been loaded as due to an `autoload` form created when the `slime` package was installed, such that the `slime` interactive command would load `slime` (dot-elc or dot-el) to define the actual `slime` command. Emacs then tries to load every library that has a `require` form in `slime.el`, when evaluating the bytecode (or source code) for `slime.el`, thus to the point where the macroexpansion (??) fails.

After recompiling `hyperspec.el`, hopefully it might serve to clear up any possible issue with the compiled macroexpansion form, at this instance.

I don't believe it should be necessary to restart Emacs, at that point. Entering the interactive `slime` command in the minibuffer again then, does the issue clear up somehow?

If that does not work out, then if simply loading that `hyperspec.el` as a  source file -- as instead of its (ordinarily preferred) `hyperspec.elc` -- this might serve to work around the issue, albeit, skipping any optimizations in any byte-compiled form of the file. Removing `hyperspec.elc` would be one way to approach this, as to ensure that `hyperspec.el` is loaded instead.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I followed them but got:

```
Compiling file /Users/username/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.26.1/lib/hyperspec.el at Thu Apr 28 19:41:41 2022
hyperspec.el:1318:1: Error: Wrong number of arguments: (3 . 4), 2
```

Comment: I did not have `hyperspec.els` in `~/.emacs.d/slime-2.26.1/lib` but `hyperspec.el~` so not sure what the tilde is about. I removed that file  but I'm still getting package cl is deprecated error.

Comment: You will keep getting tyhe depreciation error until slime is rewritten but it is not an error and everything will work proerly for cl. It is a warning that a future emacs will remove cl but that has not happened yet.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I had the same problem.  I finished fixing the problem. In hyperspec.el I altered the line:

(define-obsolete-variable-alias 'common-lisp-glossary-fun
  'common-lisp-hyperspec-glossary-function "unknown")

by adding that last string "unknown". It is supposed to represent when something becomes obsolete. I could then byte-compile-file just fine, and slime now loads.

Comment: @DrewMills Thanks its works, but what happened? What it's trade off and what I must watch for, if something break.